# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: @TrevorSeward I'd like to nominate you to the election

Comment: Bummed I missed the notification about the nominations phase (due to being under 300 rep). Would've been great to be made aware of the opportunity to ask questions of the candidates based on their experience.

Comment: There are only two candidates for this election, which is only marginally better than Russia,  North Korea and the UK.  Do we need more candidates?  Do we actually need to elect extra mods?  The candidate scores are really low, as they've not really participated in a meaningful way on the site.  That's how it appears based on the e.g. 3/40 score...

Comment: There is a discussion going on related to restarting the SharePoint election. Those who want to contribute to this discussion can visit [Should we restart the SharePoint election?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/should-we-restart-the-sharepoint-election/1593).